# How to retrieve page parameters from jquery load not url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a menu:

```
$("#Menu").load("js/menu/menu.html?active=menu_home");
```

But within the menu.html page, I want to set the active page. However I want to retrieve the JQuery parameters not the current browser parameters.

My url must remain "example.com" and the loaded jquery page must set the active element without requiring the web browser url to change.

Comment: Could please try to explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: You're trying to keep the active tab passed as a url param ?